# How to disable SSH cloning of repo on Azure Devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ssh

I want that the users(contributers, readers) shouldn't clone the repo hosted on azure devops to their personal (non-comapany) laptops

I didn't get any method to do so yet. Currently, using ssh-cloning i can clone the repo hosted on azure devops to my personal laptop (non-company/non-compliant) laaptops. Is it possible to restrict such access using CAS policies? or is there any other way to do so?

Comment: you can use a combination of strategies that focus on controlling access based on device compliance and user authentication context such as leverage Azure Active Directory (MS Entra) Conditional Access Policies (CAS) along with other strategies to achieve this then check for aspects like whether the device is enrolled in the MDM, or ensuring that devices are hybrid Azure AD joined or implement network-level controls that restrict access to Azure DevOps services to certain IP ranges, such as those of your company network or VPN.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider to use `conditional access policy`，but it's used to restrict/allow `access` to Microsoft resources(DevOps org), `not only` SSH clone.

Please check the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/change-application-access-policies?view=azure-devops#conditional-access-policies) for the details.

[image]

Or you can consider to disable the `SSH authentication` on DevOps organization settings -> `Security` -> `Policies` page. It will disable SSH clone for all users.

[image]